# On Unix how do I get the output from the diff command to look like a man page? Where I can press 'b' or 'f' to read further or back?

Tags: diff, man

You know how when you use the man command to read the manual (e.g. `man ls`) and you get output that is paginated that you can read from top to bottom by pressing 'f' to go read further down and 'b' to read further up (assuming you're reading from top to bottom left to right) and you press 'q' to quit. I want the output from diff to behave the same way because sometimes I have a long list of differences to read but I find myself having to scroll all the way up in the terminal to read the beginning of the output.

The Git diff command does this and I've come to like it (e.g. `git diff` ) but I don't always have the luxury of having all my files under version control.

The best I can think off is piping the out put of the diff command to some other command but I'm not sure which. Can anyone help? Does this sort of output behavior provided (like man pages) have a name for future reference?

Comment: Another idea, that doesn't exactly answer your question, is that if you like the `git diff` - why not use it? Even if your files are not under version control, git can still show the diffs, using the interface you're used to.

Answer (score 11):

### It's called "paging output" or (somewhat erroneously) "pagination" …

… and `man` does it by invoking your preferred pager shell command, named by your `PAGER` environment variable, upon the output of whatever pipeline was used to generate the output form of the manual page.  It falls back to a default if you haven't specified a pager command.  On early Unices the default pager program, that `man` invokes as the default pager command with known hardwired options, was `pg`.  On your system it is probably `more` or `less`.  Some `man` commands look at other environment variables for pager commands, as well.

*You* do it by doing what `man` is doing: pipe the output of what you want to see into the standard input of a pager program.

You should get yourself a good book on Unix.  There are a fair few that explain this, which is a very basic feature of the system.  A simple Google Books search for `pager unix more` by me today turned up over a hundred books that discuss this.  (I stopped counting at a hundred.)

Answer (score 10):

The program auxiliary that `man` and `git diff` invoke is called a [**pager**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). On modern systems, the default pager is called **`less`**. Several decades ago, the first pager was `more`, so called because it displayed one page then waited for you to press a key to see “more”. Then came `less`, which also let you go back (to see less, so to speak), confirming the saying that “less is more” (than more).

`git diff` is a bit of an exception; the `diff` utility, the `cvs diff` subcommand, `svn diff` subcommand and so on just do their job of computing the diff and printing it out. If you want to page through the diff, you need to invoke a pager explicitly:

```
diff file.old file.new | less
```

If you want to use a different pager for `man`, `git diff` and other commands that call a pager, you can set the `PAGER` environment variable, for example by putting this in the file `~/.profile`:

```
export PAGER=most
```

You can't make commands such as `diff` invoke a pager automatically. You can make a wrapper function though (to be put in your shell initialization file, e.g. `~/.zshrc` for zsh or `~/.bashrc` for bash):

```
diff () {
  if [ -t 1]; then             # If standard output is a terminal
    command "$@" | less        #    then pipe through less
  else                         # else
    command "$@"               #     run the command (and return its exit status)
  fi
}
```

Warning: such a function can be disruptive sometimes. You can also make a one-character alias for your pager, e.g.

```
alias p=less P=less
```

so you can type `diff … |p` or `diff … |P` when you want to page through the output of a command.

Answer (score 4):

How about using the less command...EX:

```
 ls -l | less -CM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the diff content in vim:

```
git diff | view -
```

Of course you can:

```
diff -u a.txt b.txt | view -
```

Enjoy!